# Matrix integration with Keycloak without browser flow using JWT token

Tags: authentication, matrix, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect

I am using the Matrix chat server and already integrated SSO with Keycloak.

I see some APIs by the Matrix server lead to the Keycloak login page to enter credentials.

I do not need this and want to use Keycloak provided JWT token to log in users with the Matrix server. I need to log in the user to the Matrix server in the backend with the same password user set in the application.

Is there any way to do it without a browser login flow?

The Keycloak access token does not work with the Matrix server even though I can connect to the Matrix server from the element.io web app which leads me to the Keycloak login page.